# Given a HttpResponseMessage, how do I read the content of the request?

Tags: c#

Given a `System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage`, I can get quite a lot of information about the request I made through `response.RequestMessage`, for example

```
response.RequestMessage.RequestUri // the url of the request
response.RequestMessage.Method     // the HTTP method
```

However, I can't figure out a way to get something useful from

```
response.RequestMessage.Content    // a StringContent instance
```

I've looked through the property tree of the `StringContent`, but I can't figure out how to get its contents as a regular string in a way that works in the Watch Window.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `ReadAsStringAsync()`.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: doing that in a Watch window throws a `System.ObjectDisposedException`. Thanks for the tip, though!

Comment: Are you watching it after it's disposed? Then I would expect that to happen. You can't watch an object that's been disposed although maybe there are some tricks in there to copy the value. But the expression itself can't be evaluated again. Are you using VS2015? I recall reading that watch expressions are now better supported.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: VS2013, and I'm watching it after the response comes back, so it's very possible that the request object has had its content disposed... Any ideas on how to obtain the contents of the request body from a `HttpResponseMessage`?

Comment: I'm using VS2015 and after putting a watch on `msg.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result` and disposing the message, I still see the value in the watch window (but greyed out). The sample code I tried is this: https://dotnetfiddle.net/atnCPS

Comment: @JeroenVannevel "greyed out" doesn't count: it means the value has become obsolete since the last evaluation and is merely preserved for your convenience.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev: sounds to me like that is exactly what Tomas needs.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: There are two problems with your approach: 1) it requires me to stop before *every* request, which means stopping much more often than I'd like, for no reason. 2) It relies on the responses coming back in order, and before any other request is made; otherwise, I'll have stale data in the watch window and won't be able to match up what was sent in the request that gave the failed response.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Analyzing [`System.Net.Http.dll v2.2.29.0`](https://api.nuget.org/packages/microsoft.net.http.2.2.29.nupkg) with [ILSpy](http://ilspy.net/) shows that `System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.CreateResponseMessage` (that initializes an `HttpResponse` object) doesn't do anything with the corresponding `HttpRequest`'s `.Content`. That means that if it wasn't `null` in the first place, the *content object itself* should still be available.

[`System.ObjectDisposedException`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.objectdisposedexception%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) is thrown **"when an operation is performed on a disposed object."** What does a "disposed object" mean? `System.Net.Http.StringContent` turns out to implement `System.IDisposable` through its ancestor, `System.Net.Http.HttpContent`.
So, it actually means **"an `IDisposable` after its `.Dispose()` method was called."**

Naturally, searching for `HttpContent.Dispose()` users brings us to **the culprit - `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsync()`** that calls `System.Net.Http.HttpClient.DisposeRequestContent()` after sending the data.

---

Now, regarding what to do. All that `HttpContent.Dispose()` does is close the object's streams and set a flag. However, `StreamContent` (or rather its parent, `ByteArrayContent`) **keeps the data in the `.content` field** - which isn't touched by the disposition!

Alas, both methods that read it directly are `protected`, and all the public methods that use those check the flag first. **So, the only way to read it is with reflection** (the illustration is in IronPython, notes are given for C# equivalents):

```
>>> sc=System.Net.Http.StringContent("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
#in C#, the following is `type(StringContent)' (this is what it actually does)
>>> scd=System.Reflection.TypeDelegator(System.Net.Http.StringContent)
>>> print scd.GetField("content",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
None     #because the field is in ByteArrayContent and is private
>>> bacd=System.Reflection.TypeDelegator(System.Net.Http.ByteArrayContent)
>>> bacd.GetField("content",System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic|System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance)
<System.Reflection.RtFieldInfo object at 0x000000000000002C [Byte[] content]>
# `_' is last result
>>> _.GetValue(sc)
Array[Byte]((<System.Byte object at 0x000000000000002D [97]>, <System.Byte objec
t at 0x000000000000002E [98]>, <System.Byte object at 0x000000000000002F [99]>,
<...>
```

In C#, this would look like:

```
type(ByteArrayContent)
    .GetField("content",BindingFlags.NonPublic|BindingFlags.Instance)
    .GetValue(content)
```

Comment: OK. Reflection is definitely overkill for my use case (debugging...) so I'll leave this be. Thanks for the thorough digging and explanation, though!

Comment: You can read the field in the debugger just as well. It uses reflection to explore objects if you didn't know ;-)