# correctly disposing HttpWebResponse in exception

Tags: c#

consider the following function taken from Microsoft doc:

```
void webREquest(url) {
  // taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx
  try {
     // Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site" strong in the Create call with a invalid name.
     HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);

    // Get the associated response for the above request.
    HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse) myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    myHttpWebResponse.Close();
  }
  catch(WebException e) {
    Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run."+
              "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
    if(e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError) {
      Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
      Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
    }
  }
  catch(Exception e) {
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
  }
}
```

I have a few questions about the way objects are disposed or indisposed:

- `myHttpWebRequest` is not directly closed/disposed - is this really unnecessary ? When is the request closed in this case ? how can I make sure it is closed as soon as possible ?
- in the `WebException` catch block, is it not necessary to somehow dispose/close `e.Response` (which is of type `HttpWebResponse`) ? if not where/how it is disposed ?
- Wouldn't it be better to have a `using` clause around `myHttpWebRequest` and `myHttpWebResponse` ? but if so, would that make `e.Response` in the exception handler inaccessible ?
- What is the meaning of the "This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run" above ?

I need to make sure absolutely no connection stays after the function exits ...

Comment: [Request `.Content` is disposed after the the request is sent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30643994/given-a-httpresponsemessage-how-do-i-read-the-content-of-the-request/30881737#30881737)

Comment: I don't understand what is this in relation to ?

Answer (score 1):

> myHttpWebRequest is not directly closed/disposed - is this really
>   unnecessary? When is the request closed in this case? how can I make
>   sure it is closed as soon as possible?

Yes, but considering the class does not implement a IDisposable interface it might seem that it is ok not to.

> in the WebException catch block, is it not necessary to somehow
>   dispose/close e.Response (which is of type HttpWebResponse)? if not
>   where/how it is disposed?

I would recommend closing it in the finally block to handle both exception and non-expection scenario

> Wouldn't it be better to have a using clause around myHttpWebRequest
>   and myHttpWebResponse? but if so, would that make e.Response in the
>   exception handler inaccessible?

Unfortunately HttpWebRequest does not implement IDisposable so you cannot use using in this case

> What is the meaning of the "This program is expected to throw
>   WebException on successful run" above?

It is mentioned in the comment that request is made to an invalid site so it is expected to throw exception

```
void webREquest(string url)
        {
            // taken from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx
            HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = null;
            HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = null;
            try
            {
                // Create a web request for an invalid site. Substitute the "invalid site" strong in the Create call with a invalid name.
                myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);

                // Get the associated response for the above request.
                myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();
                myHttpWebResponse.Close();
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This program is expected to throw WebException on successful run." +
                          "\n\nException Message :" + e.Message);
                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.ProtocolError)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status Code : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusCode);
                    Console.WriteLine("Status Description : {0}", ((HttpWebResponse)e.Response).StatusDescription);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                //close on myHttpWebResponse
                myHttpWebResponse?.Close();

                //mark myHttpWebRequest for collection
                myHttpWebRequest = null;
            }
        }
```

Comment: thx! ... "I would recommend closing it in the finally block to handle both exception and non-expection scenario " - can you show sample code pls ?